# R: Transform factor to Datetime showing time as well

Tags: r, datetime, posixct

I have a factor column `DATE` in a dataframe `a` that shows dates written like this:

```
01/01/2012 00
```

It shows the day, the month, the year and the hour.

On stackoverflow I found this way to transform from factor to datetime:

```
a$DATE <- as.POSIXct(as.character(a$DATE), format = "%d/%m/%Y %H")
```

However when I try to check the dataframe by `View(a)` I only get to see the date without the hour. All the dates appear like this:

```
2012-01-01
```

I have also tried to specify datetime by saving the dataframe in a csv and importing it again through the Rstudio button "Import Dataset". When I specify the type by clicking on the header of the DATE column I get the same error: the hour doesn't show.

Is the method I used correct?
If yes, how can I show the hour?
If it's not possible to show the hour, how can I get the hour from the POSIXct type?

Answer (score 0):

I can't seem to reproduce your issue, could you possible provide [a complete minimal reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonste the issue?

Here's what I got.

```
times <- c("01/01/2012 00", "30/11/2013 11", "17/03/2014 23")
times_factor <- as.factor(times)
times_factor
#> [1] 01/01/2012 00 30/11/2013 11 17/03/2014 23
#> Levels: 01/01/2012 00 17/03/2014 23 30/11/2013 11

foo <- as.POSIXct(times_factor, format = "%d/%m/%Y %H")
foo
#> [1] "2012-01-01 00:00:00 CET" "2013-11-30 11:00:00 CET" "2014-03-17 23:00:00 CET"

bar <- format(foo,"%d/%m/%Y %H")
bar
#> [1] "01/01/2012 00" "30/11/2013 11" "17/03/2014 23"

# install.packages(c("tidyverse"), dependencies = TRUE)
library(lubridate)
dmy_h(times_factor, quiet = T, tz = "CET")
#> [1] "2012-01-01 00:00:00 CET" "2013-11-30 11:00:00 CET" "2014-03-17 23:00:00 CET"
```

Comment: Using dmy_hm yields a date in the year 2020. Using dmy_h gives the correct date but does not show the hour. I think the question is about displaying POSIXct objects in Rstudio, not about converting these to characters.

Comment: @Pigna, could you possible provide [a complete minimal reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) based on the code I posted above? Something we can work from and use understand the issue?